# Removing outliers using box plot

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from my dataset but I doesn't seem to be working. I have tested this technique on a vector of numbers and it worked. However, when trying to apply it to a dataset coming from a csv file. It doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing something wrong or am I approaching outlier removal completely wrong?

- Original dataset had "Sample" number as the first column in the csv file and "Class" (van, car, etc..) as the final column and so I removed these columns from the dataset

[image]
After outlier removal (not sure if correct)
[image]

Testing on CSV File data

```
vehicles <- read.csv("C:/Users/Documents/vehiclescsv.csv") #load csv file
vehicles2 <- vehicles[,-1] #remove first column "Sample" number
vehicles3 <- vehicles2[,-19] #remove final column "Class" name
vehData <- vehicles3
vehClass <- vehicles$Class #store final column, class name

boxplot(vehData) #plot data to see outliers
OutVals <- boxplot(vehData)$out #find and store outliers
OutVals
vehDataRemoveOut <- vehData[!(vehData%in%OutVals)] #remove the outliers
length(vehData) - length(vehDataRemoveOut)# see if outliers have been removed
boxplot(vehDataRemoveOut) #re-plot to see changes
```

Testing on vector

```
x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,1000)
boxplot(x)
OutVals <- boxplot(x)$out
OutVals

RemovedOut <- x[!(x %in%OutVals)]
length(x) - length(RemovedOut)

boxplot(RemovedOut)
```

Data for testing dput(head()) - As requested

```
 vehData <-
  structure(
    list(
      Samples = 1:6,
      Comp = c(95L, 91L, 104L, 93L, 85L,
               107L),
      Circ = c(48L, 41L, 50L, 41L, 44L, 57L),
      D.Circ = c(83L,
                 84L, 106L, 82L, 70L, 106L),
      Rad.Ra = c(178L, 141L, 209L, 159L,
                 205L, 172L),
      Pr.Axis.Ra = c(72L, 57L, 66L, 63L, 103L, 50L),
      Max.L.Ra = c(10L,
                   9L, 10L, 9L, 52L, 6L),
      Scat.Ra = c(162L, 149L, 207L, 144L, 149L,
                  255L),
      Elong = c(42L, 45L, 32L, 46L, 45L, 26L),
      Pr.Axis.Rect = c(20L,
                       19L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 28L),
      Max.L.Rect = c(159L, 143L, 158L, 143L,
                     144L, 169L),
      Sc.Var.Maxis = c(176L, 170L, 223L, 160L, 241L, 280L),
      Sc.Var.maxis = c(379L, 330L, 635L, 309L, 325L, 957L),
      Ra.Gyr = c(184L,
                 158L, 220L, 127L, 188L, 264L),
      Skew.Maxis = c(70L, 72L, 73L,
                     63L, 127L, 85L),
      Skew.maxis = c(6L, 9L, 14L, 6L, 9L, 5L),
      Kurt.maxis = c(16L,
                     14L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L),
      Kurt.Maxis = c(187L, 189L, 188L, 199L,
                     180L, 181L),
      Holl.Ra = c(197L, 199L, 196L, 207L, 183L, 183L),
      Class = c("van", "van", "saab", "van", "bus", "bus")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not quite clear: what is the problem? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No error just identifies the outliers when doing OutVals <- boxplot(vehData)$out but when trying to remove them through vehDataRemoveOut <- vehData[!(vehData %in%OutVals)] it doesn't seem to remove anything and the box plot remains the same

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your dataframe with `dput(head())`?

Comment: I have added the results of dput(head(vehData)) to the post :D

Comment: Plz provide `dput` in **reproducible** form (just as code)!

Comment: Oh sorry. Sure I will try and do that, not done it before

Comment: I have added the vehData structure using dput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem is that you are not removing the outliers from each column. Here's a `base R` solution:

Data:

```
x <- c(1,0.8,3,4,10,0.01)
y <- c(1, 7, 0.5, 0.8,0.7, 1.1)
z <- c(0,0.1,0.2, 5, 0.5,0.6)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

The boxplot looks like this:
[image]

Now store the outliers in a vector:

```
a <- boxplot(df)$out
```

And `sapply`a function to remove them from the `df`as a whole (ie, each column):

```
df_new <- sapply(df, function(x) x[!x %in% a])
```

The boxplot after removal:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I think this might have worked. I tried this and added my result at the top on the post, comparing before and after. Have I done this correctly? Also would you mind explaining a little how this line of code works df_new <- sapply(df, function(x) x[!x %in% a]) :: I don't quite understand it, I am new to R :)

Comment: If it helped please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer. You updated boxplot looks rather good (except for one or two outliers that have remained).

Comment: To remove the final ones, I would just repeat the process? Thanks again for the help. I have also accepted the answer.

Comment: well you can try repeating the procedure but whether that's an appropriate method to use I don't know ...

Comment: On second thoughts, note that removing the outliers is no guarantee that the revised dataset will **not** have outliers too because R calculates what are typical and untypical data points **anew** with each new set of data. For example, once one extreme data point is removed, then the next rather untypical data point may become the new outlier in the new distribution.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I noticed this. I have just made a function that applies the outlier removal to all columns so long as $out has values contained, suggesting outliers. After around 4 attempts, it no longer picked up on any outliers and my data seemed good. I assume this means this technique should be fine to repeat and use? Thanks again for helping me out